# MySQL 5.6 - Procedure to remove all duplicates except one with the highest value?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table where I want to remove all duplicates of col_2, and keep only the one with the largest value.

```
-----------------------
| col_1 | col_2 | ... |
----------------|-----|
| 2     |  2    | ... |
| 3     |  2    | ... |
| 4     |  2    | ... |
----------------------
```

Would return:

```
-----------------------
| col_1 | col_2 | ... |
----------------|-----|
| 4     |  2    | ... |
----------------------
```

However I unfortunately designed my table such that there are no unique indices or keys.

What is the procedure I have to make in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a couple of group by and a tuple

```
delete from my_table a 
inner join (
    select col_2
    from my_table
    group by col_2
    having count(*)> 1
) t on a.col_2 = t.col_2
where (a.col_2, a.col_1) not in (
    select col_2, max(col_1)
    from my_table 
    group by col_2
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

the join is for get only the col_2 with at least a duplicated  row and the not in is for delete the row not max(col_1)